# Will the relay break if the disconnected end voltage is too high

Tags: power, relay, protection, mains

I'm trying to create a simple overvoltage protection circuit.
In brief, there are times when my mains voltage goes well over 250V (normally 220) and I want to switch off the whole thing connected to this circuit.
Mains goes to the Common contact and the load to NC contact.

I currently have [this relay](http://www.components.omron.com/components/web/pdflib.nsf/0/D8107CD58D8B96D185257201007DD580/%24file/mk_0607.pdf).

Question: I'm not quite sure what the rated contact voltage means (on connected end or disconnected end or just when switching or all), but if the mains goes to something like 300V will the relay break?
The relay will only be switching if the mains is around 250V and if it rises to 300V it will just stay disconnected, but I'm the sure if this is allowable

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be OK. On page 3 it has this: -

> 1,000 VAC, 50/60 Hz for 1 minute between contacts of same poles,
>   between terminals of the same polarity

And if there is any doubt still in your mind then you can wire contacts from the same relay in series. And if there is a doubt about this, each contact can be in parallel with a small non-polarized capacitor such as 1nF - this will equalize the voltages when open circuit.

Comment: So, 400VAC for hours would be OK?
What about the 'Operating Voltage' on Contact data, what is it for? Since there should be no voltage drop when the relay is in closed state, isn't it?

Comment: I'd use two contacts in series (with 1nF balancing capacitors) for 400VAC or a different relay. 400VAC is a bit much for these relays I would say.

Comment: How do you connect them in series if they are opened?

Comment: If the relay has two separate relay contacts (hopefully) they need to be in series - both need to be either NC. Then across each you put a 1nF capacitor rated for full AC voltage - this balances the AC across each open contact.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you. The current setup is NC to load
CC to high voltage NO is left unconnected
I designed a circuit so that if the mains rise above certain threshold it will trigger the relay and cut power from the load (or maybe connect NO to an LED to indicate the status if  possible)
So do I just connect CC1 to mains, NO1 to cap then to CC2 and NO2 open?

Comment: Most of the relays you linked are double-pole i.e. two separate relay contacts. I'd wire both sets of contacts in series so that they share the open circuit voltage of 400VAC i.e. each see 220VAC but, to make sure you put 1nF across each open contact to balance the voltage sharing.